# How can I deal with the following error I get when I use Dean Edwards' IE7.js with IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, ie7.js

I'm using [Dean Edwards' IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) for IE6

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE7.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

and getting a JavaScript error on IE 6 when it reads the line:

```
c.runtimeStyle[h]=c.parentElement.currentStyle[h]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe IE6 has a parentElement property.  You might be able to get around this by including this code in the `<!--[if lt ie7]>` tag:

```
Element.prototype.parentElement = Element.prototype.parentNode;
```

Comment: but for IE7 i don't need this javascript. I use this only for IE6.

Comment: Actually `parentElement` is IE-only.