# Is there any jquery version of IE7.js available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, ie7.js

I need jquery version of IE7.js or any other similar jquery based js for same thing?

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: How does the "plain" version not work with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>This script has nothing to do with jQuery.

You don't need a jQuery version of it.</strike>

I'm leaving this answer for David's comment.

Comment: some methods of this script does not work in IE. and it create some other problem with some javascript also

Comment: Since it overwrites various JS functions so they act in a standard fashion, anything in jQuery that calls those functions and compensates for the browser being IE6 could end up with double compensation and break.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger - see here 1.http://brilla.org/archives/tag/ie7-js 2. http://markmail.org/message/myc7ajbr3g2edx2s 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774519/how-can-i-deal-with-the-following-error-i-get-when-i-use-dean-edwards-ie7-js-wit

Answer (score 2):

Large chunks of what IE7.js does are built into jQuery (providing you use the jQuery API to write your own functions).

So the answer is: Yes, jQuery.

As for the bits which it doesn't cover — you need to look for specific solutions for those bits (but only the ones you actually care about).

Answer (score 0):

it's not a jquery version of whole IE7.js but i found it's useful

http://www.impressivewebs.com/buggy-css-selectors-cross-browser-jquery/