# Detecting if IE7 or lower with conditional comments and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to check if a person is using anything IE with version less than 8 or anything else.

I use conditional comments to declare boolean..

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">var badIE = true;</script>
<![endif]-->
```

And now I check in my js file the boolean like this:

```
if (badIE == true){
    alert('You have bad IE!');
} else {
    alert('Bueno!');
}
```

If I use IE7 or IE6, it alerts that "You have bad IE!". If I use anything else, it should alert "Bueno!", but it does not. What is the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to declare the `badIE` variable as false first in order for it to work, or else the code outside of the conditional knows **nothing** about `badIE`

Try this:

```
<script>
    var badIE = false;
</script>

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">badIE = true;</script>
<![endif]-->

<script>
if (badIE == true){
    alert('You have bad IE!');
} else {
    alert('Bueno!');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer (Neal has you covered), but you may also be interested in: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

From the page:

> IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser. It fixes many HTML and CSS issues and makes transparent PNG work correctly under IE5 and IE6.

Though if you're using jQuery, keep in mind that it does [many of the same things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387787/is-there-any-jquery-version-of-ie7-js-available) as this library.

Comment: Does it also include png fix when fading in or out transparent images? That is the whole reason I'm messing with it...

Comment: If you click the link, it does cover .png! Cool stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditional statement `<!--[if lt IE 8]> ... <![endif]-->` means that the code between those will not be executed if the web browser is not an IE version less than 8, which means `var badIE` will never be declared for all other browsers (i.e., FireFox, IE8, IE9, Safari, etc.)

Because it is never declared, you are getting a silent scripting error in the background when the browser tries to execute `if (badIE == true){`, which means the browser immediately stops reading the script and does not try to execute the `alert('Bueno!');` statement.